# C# Perceptron Algorithm (Reading in a file)

Tags: c#, algorithm, streamreader, readfile, perceptron

I'm currently creating a simple single layer perceptron algorithm. It should take in a .txt file and the algorithm runs over it. At the moment, I have the algorithm and just hard coded sample data values to test if it works (which it does), but I need it to feed off existing data values from a file. I have tried to make it work, but due to my inexperience in coding, I haven't succeeded. It would be awesome if someone could help me get this code working with external data as I've been pulling my hair out. The data is formatted like below (obviously without the bullet numbers).

1. 0.651769
2. 0.651604
3. 0.651609
4. 0.651679
5. 0.651667
6. 0.651699

Current Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Network
{
public class Network

{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Load sample input patterns.
        double[,] inputs = new double[,] {

            {0.99, 0.99}, {0.99, 0.99}, {0.99, 0.99}, {0.99, 095}};

        // Load sample output patterns.
        int[] outputs = new int[] {0, 1, 0, 0 };
        int patternCount = inputs.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;

        // Randomise weights.
        Random rdm = new Random();

        // Setting randomly generated weights between -0.5 and +0.5
        double[] weights = {rdm.NextDouble()-0.5, rdm.NextDouble()-0.5, rdm.NextDouble()};

        // Set learning rate.
        double learningRate = 1;

        // Start iteration at 0
        int iteration = 1;
        double ErrorRate;

        do
        {   
            // Global error set to 0
            ErrorRate = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < patternCount; j++)
            {
                // Calculate output.
                int output = Output(weights, inputs[j, 0], inputs[j, 1]);
                // Calculate error.
                double localError = outputs[j] - output;

                //if the localError is not equal to zero
                if (localError != 0)
                {
                    // Update weights.
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        weights[i] += learningRate * localError * inputs[j, i] / 2;
                    }
                }
                // Convert error to absolute value.
                ErrorRate += (localError);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0}\tError {1}", iteration, ErrorRate);
            iteration++;

         // If the Error is equal to zero then calculate
        } while (ErrorRate != 0);

        // Convergence
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[Input1] [Input2] [Output]");
        // Input1 values
        for (double input1 = 0; input1 <= 1; input1 += 1)
        {
        // Input2 values
            for (double input2 = 0; input2 <= 1; input2 += 1)
            {
                // Calculate output with the inputs and the randomly generated weights
                int output = Output(weights, input1, input2);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine("    {0}         {1}        {2}", input1, input2, (output == 1) ? "1" : "0");
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static int Output(double[] weights, double input1, double input2)
    {
        //  Output = input1 * weight1 + input2 * weight2 + bias * weight3
        double sum = input1 * weights[0] + input2 * weights[1] + 1 * weights[2];

        // If the first condition is true, then it becomes the result. If not, the second condition becomes the result
        return (sum >= 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Read about creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Basically, remove `perceptron` and `algorithm` from your question and all the code around that and ask how to "Read in a text file". Then someone can mark it as a duplicate and point you to some answers. What format is your text file in? Csv? One input per line? I see no code where you tried to read in a text file.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what is wrong.  Which part of your code isn't working?

Comment: I need the code below to be changed to reading in a txt file (no other format) line by line from top to bottom, which I've had problems with. At the moment the algorithm is just running from hard coded data values inside an array with a double type. 

    double[,] inputs = new double[,] {

    {0.99, 0.99}, {0.99, 0.99}, {0.99, 0.99}, {0.99, 095}};

Comment: I found the answer @Patrick, it's listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+read+numbers+from+text+file)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
  using System.Globalization; 
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq

  ...

  double[] data = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt") //TODO: put actual file here
    .Select(line => Double.Parse(line, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray();
```